# Mysema Querydsl - Enum to String

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, querydsl, mysema

Example:

```
public enum ShapeType {
    CIRCLE, SQUARE, RECTANGLE TRIANGLE
}

public ShapeEnity {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ShapeType shapeType;
    .......
}

public ShapeDTO {
    private String shapeType;
    ....
}


public ShapeFinder {
    public ShapeDTO find() {
        QShape shape = QShape.shape;
        return createQuery()
            .from(shape)
            .list(Projections.fields(ShapeDTO.class,
                shape.shapeType.stringValue
            ))
    }
}
```

As in the example above, I would like to get string value of enum ShapeType in DTO object. How should this conversion look like?
I tried as in the example above and looks good, but when I use shapeType.stringValue() and then Hibernate create query with call function to_char(Oracle) or str (Sybase), as in example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ShapeType) From Shape;
```

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Edit please, seems ununderstandable

Comment: I can't believe, that it may even compile... `@Enumerated("EnumType.STRING")` this part should looks like `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, both from package `javax.persistence`

Comment: @Krzysiek, Yes you're right, but it's not important... this is an illustrative example...